# I have multiple jPickers on same page ,how do i open single jPicker dialog at a time?

Tags: jquery, jpicker

Using multiple jPickers on same page, my problem is when i'm clicking on all three one by one it keeps open. Is there any event or method in jPicker through i can open single dialog at a time? I have checked on [jPicker's site](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) they have same problem all dialogs keeps open.

snippet of js code ,

```
$(function() {
  $('#id1').jPicker();
});
$(function() {
  $('#id2').jPicker();
});
$(function() {
  $('#id3').jPicker();
});
```

Comment: jPicker looks a bit poor to me, as it lacks standard functionality like callbacks and multiple pickers implementation without overlapping. Have a look at this one http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ Good luck!

Comment: thanks but it doesn't match my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event handler to an elem such that it closes all the open `jPicker` dialogs,

The logic is jPicker has containers added to the DOM in the same order as they are initialized using `.jPicker()` , so we close the dialogs of all other containers except the clicked container .

This seemed to be working on the demo page..

```
//For #id1 jPicker
  $("span.Image").click(function(){
    $('div.jPicker.Container').not(':eq('+$("span.Image").index($(this))+')').find('table input.Cancel').trigger('click');
 });
```

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DksEw/1/)

Comment: Updated my code..this is only for the first one ...If you could provide a fiddle i would be able to help you better  :)

Comment: On fiddle it seems quite complicated to do but I'll make demo and let you know.

Comment: can i have that demo page link please?

Comment: can you post your demo link ?

Comment: I meant i tried my code on the jPicker demo page , by pasting code on the console , and it worked :)

Comment: I see! what about other ids? i mean as you have mentioned eq(1) for first id , right?

Comment: Sure,i'll check and let you know.

Comment: Where to put this code ? After my $('#id1').jPicker(); ? Or in document ready?

Comment: After all the jPicker initializations

Comment: I hope you are loading jQuery library