# jPicker reset background color on reset button and how i get opened single jPicker dialog at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jpicker

In my jPicker i wants to reset background color and HTML reset button reset the value of textbox and  jPicker has filling background color to particular textbox and its not getting reset.
So my question is , Do i need to use custom any jQuery function to reset the background color also?
Or HTML reset button could do that , if yes then how?

And How do it get single dialog open at a time, if page has multiple jPickers? Adding my previous question here which was unanswered till now :( [I have multiple jPickers on same page ,how do i open single jPicker dialog at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431532/i-have-multiple-jpickers-on-same-page-how-do-i-open-single-jpicker-dialog-at-a)

Attaching my code to [`EXAMPLE CODE`](http://jsfiddle.net/DksEw/)

Answer (score 1):

Use following jQuery Code for reset button

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('.Multiple').jPicker();
        $("#resetbutton").click(function(){
           $(".Multiple").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
        });
    });
```

And use following HTML set ID in html of reset button

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" id="resetbutton"/>
```

**Changes for At a time 1 jPicker**
Revised HTML Code

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<form>
<input class="Multiple" id="t1" type="text" value="" /><br />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

<input class="Multiple" id="t2" type="text" value="" /><br />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input class="Multiple" id="t3" type="text" value="" />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" id="resetbutton"/>
</form>
```

Revised jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('.Multiple').jPicker(function(){
        });

        $(".jPicker").click(function(){

            for(var i=0;i<$.jPicker.List.length;i++)
            {
                if($.jPicker.List[i].id != $(this).prev().attr("id"))
                {
                    $.jPicker.List[i].hide();
                }

            }


        });
        $("#resetbutton").click(function(){
           $(".Multiple").css("background-color","#fff");

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But what about dialog open issue?